# Use a shell script to replace text with pwd

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace, pwd

**file.txt**

```
...
<LOCAL_PATH_TO_REPO>/src/java/example.java
...
```

^A longer file but this pretty much explains what I am trying to do.

**script.sh**

```
dir=$(pwd)
# replace <LOCAL_PATH_TO_REPO> with dir
```

I tried using the `sed` command but it did not work for some reason. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @anubhava Ran `sed "s/<LOCAL_PATH_TO_REPO>/$PWD/" file.yml` and got the following error:
`sed: 1: "s/<LOCAL_PATH_TO_REPO>/ ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'U'`

Comment: Sorry use: `sed "s~LOCAL_PATH_TO_REPO~$PWD~" file.yml`

Comment: @anubhava That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your error means you have backslashes in the variable text.

The simplest solution is to change the delimiter to the one that does not occur in the variable text.

If there are no commas use a comma:

```
sed -i "s,LOCAL_PATH_TO_REPO,$PWD," file.yml
```

The `-i` flag introduces changes into the input file (works for GNU `sed`).